# Selecting all divs except one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

```
<div id="main">
 <div class="a"></div>
 <div class="b"><p>not me</p></div>
 <div class="b"></div>
 <div class="b"></div>
 <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

How we can write a selector to select `all divs with class b` except whose child is `<p>not me</p>` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('div.b:not(:has(p))').........
```

Or the readable version

```
$('div.b').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).find('p').length;
});
```

If you want to match the content as well:

```
$('div.b').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('p').text() !== "not me";
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HGQj4/)

Comment: Or half-way between the two options: `$('div.b').not(':has(p)')`. Regarding the last option, I know the sample markup didn't have this problem but what if a particular div had more than one paragraph?

Answer (score 3):

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/46nC5/1/

Since you are specifically looking for `class b` made a demo for you hence sharing.

In this demo you will see the not me getting fade out, rest will stay as it is.

i.e. With `:not` + `:has` it can be done

**code**

```
$('div.b:has(p)').​
```

**or**

```
$('div.b:not(:has(p))')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.b').filter(function () {
    return $(this).find('p:contains(not me)').length == 0;
})
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sswhJ/)

Answer (score 1):

This will give you **two div** who have **class="b"** and **does not have p** (paragraph)

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PK36Z/)

```
$('div.b:not(:has(p))')
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way I usualy do:

```
$('div.b').filter(function () {
   return !$(this).hasClass('notMe');
});


<div id="main">
     <div class="a"></div>
     <div class="b notMe"><p>not me</p></div>
     <div class="b"></div>
     <div class="b"></div>
     <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

And here's another one

```
$("div.b:contains('not me')")
```

edit: sorry, here's with not

```
$("div.b:not(:contains('not me'))")
```