# jQuery combination of :not + :contains, does it work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

<sub>[(continue from other question)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11012455/601179)</sub>

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="a">aaaa</div>
     <div class="b"><p>not me</p></div>
     <div class="b">bbbb</div> <!-- select this-->
     <div class="b">bbbb</div> <!-- select this-->
     <div class="c">cccc</div>
</div> ​
```

I'm trying to select all divs with class `b` that doesn't have  `<p>not me</p>` inside of them.

I tried this:

```
$('div.b:not(:has(p:contains(not me)))').css('color', 'red');
```

But from some unknown reason it doesn't work, funny thing is, that if I remove the `:not()` part:

```
$('div.b:has(p:contains(not me))').css('color', 'blue');
```

It does select the unwanted div, so the problem must be with `:not`

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XYDk2/)

**I know there are other and even better ways,(I even gave some in that question) but I'm interested to know why `:not` + `:contains` doesn't seem together.**

Comment: @eric.itzhak. Please read the last paragraph... Or the other question.

Comment: i think :not is suppoused to work with :has...

Comment: i think culprit is `:has` not `:not`

Comment: @undefined. those can work together.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `.not` rather than `:not`:

```
$('div.b').not(':has(p:contains("not me"))').css('color', 'red');
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XYDk2/6/)

Comment: I know, I'm asking about the `:not` selector. but thanks for the input, I'll accept it if it's impossible.

Comment: @gdoron: There are a couple of existing bugs with `:not` and/or `:has`, this could be one of them... :-)

Comment: [Badge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584488/why-event-bubbles-is-false-for-focusin-and-focusout#comment13707233_10584541) My second time now... `:)`

Comment: @gdoron haha, Congratulation.

Comment: Though I decided to take a break from SO for couple of months, I think you might want to read [this ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11902) (yes, it's a bug, and it's fixed in 1.8)

Answer (score 1):

example of working **:not** + **:contains**

```
$('div.b:not(:contains("not me"))').css('color', 'cyan');
```

will change the color of all the div.b's that does NOT contain "not me".

Comment: It  really should be `:not(:contains("not me")` though. It does not take into account that the div should have a `p` element as child.

Comment: it works regardless if it contains a p or not. am i misunderstanding what you are trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with `:has`

Try this:

```
$('div.b:not(:contains(not me))').css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="a">aaaa</div>
     <div class="b"><p>not me</p></div>
     <div class="b">bbbb</div> <!-- select this-->
     <div class="b">bbbb</div> <!-- select this-->
     <div class="b"><p>no1t me</p></div>
     <div class="c">cccc</div>
</div>
```

Try this...

```
$('div.b:has(p:contains(not me))').css('color', 'green');
    
$('div.b:not(:has(p))').css('color', 'red');
    
$('div.b:has(p):not(:contains(not me))').css('color', 'blue');
```

[See the output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGxfO.png)